# rubyzip and unicode characters in filenames

Tags: ruby, zip, rubyzip

I am creating zip archive with `rubyzip` gem and `Zip::ZipOutputStream` class and have got a problem with unicode letters (cyrillic) - in archive they are presented as question marks like `????? ???? ??.doc`. Does rubyzip support unicode?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at rubyzip methods and it doesn't seem that rubyzip can change the language. It probably uses your computer's default code page. You could use chilkat zip instead as in [this](http://www.example-code.com/ruby/zip_unicode-filenames.asp) example unless you have specific requirements that cannot be addressed by chilkat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet to convert UTF-8 to [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) which cover some unicode chars (just a few). Windows 7 and older assume that filenames are encoded in CP437.

```
# first normalize the string
normalized_filename = input.mb_chars.normalize.to_s
# then encode in cp437
filename_for_zip = normalized_filename.encode("cp437")
# add file to zip
zipfile.add(filename_for_zip, pdf_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just run zip directly.

```
`cd yourfolder; zip archivename file1 file2`
```

Notice specific quotes. Worked for me on Ubuntu for Cyrillic file names, while rubyzip was generating archive with non-readable file names.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. Set this before creating the Zip file

```rb
Zip.force_entry_names_encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

I got this from https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#non-ascii-names